# Workflow diagram GUI with JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface

For my project I am looking for a JAVA library that can help me to create rich GUI of data flow diagrams. Something like: http://www.edrawsoft.com/images/software/DataFlowDiagram_full.png

I have read that Eclipse Rich Client Platform can do this. Unfortunately, the EPL license is not compatible with GPL license. Apache license or LGPL would be preferred.

Thank you for any help

Comment: You're looking for a modeling tool to be integrated into your application?

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: You want to use your app for a commercial project?

Comment: It will be open-source project - but under Apache license. I don't want to include any GPL license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of workflow engines for java here
- [Workflow Engines](http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NetBeans Visual Library](http://platform.netbeans.org/graph/) which is released under the CDDL and GPLv2

I believe it can be used [outside of a NetBeans](http://java.dzone.com/news/how-create-visual-applications) platform application as well if that is what you are looking for.